# Tkinter get values from multiple checkboxes and adding list with multiple tuples to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Good Day

I'm stuck with some code. I need to do two things: 1. Create multiple checkboxes and add the ticked boxes to a list. 2. Add multiple tuples/lists to MySQL.

Checkboxes (My code so far):

```
def weapon_submit():
    selection_list = ['Blueprint']
    ticked_items = weapon_selection.get()
    for btn in check_buttons:
        if ticked_items == 1:
            item_name = weapon_box.cget('text')
            selection_list += item_name

    # Checkboxes
    current_row = 1
    current_col = 0
    check_buttons = []
    for item in weapon_part_list:
        weapon_selection = StringVar()
        weapon_box = Checkbutton(weapon_window, text=item, variable=weapon_selection)
        weapon_box.config(bg=bg_color, fg=font_color, font=text_font, selectcolor=blue)
        weapon_box.deselect()
        weapon_box.grid(row=current_row, column=current_col, padx=15, pady=15)
        check_buttons.append(weapon_selection)
        current_row += 1
        if current_row == 4:
            current_row = 1
            current_col += 1

    # Button
    enter_button = Button(weapon_window, text="Submit", command=weapon_submit, bg=btn_color, fg=font_color, font=text_font, relief=GROOVE)
    enter_button.grid(row=5, column=2, pady=(30, 0))
```

---

Just an update if people are searching for a solution to above problem, with help from another user's post I figured it out. See below:

```
def weapon_submit():
selection_list = ['Blueprint']
for text, weapon_selection in zip(weapon_part_list, check_buttons):
    if weapon_selection.get():
        ticked_items = text
        selection_list.append(ticked_items)
```

---

Database (My code so far):

```
warframe_part_list = [
        'Blueprint',
        'Neuroptics',
        'Chassis',
        'Systems'
    ]

def number_valid(P):
    if str.isdigit(P) or str(P) == "":
          return True
    else:
          messagebox.showwarning(parent=relics_window, message="Only numbers allowed!")
      return False

vcmd = add_relics_window.register(number_valid)
prime_entry = Entry(add_relics_window, width=25, justify=CENTER, font=text_font, bg=label_color, fg=label_font_color)
prime_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=15)

  
current_row = 5
for part in warframe_part_list:
            part_label = Label(add_relics_window, text=part, font=heading_font, bg=bg_color, fg=font_color)
            part_label.grid(row=current_row, column=0)

clicked_relic = StringVar()
clicked_relic.set("Select Option")
relic_menu = OptionMenu(add_relics_window, clicked_relic, *relic_list)
relic_menu.config(bg=btn_color, fg=font_color, font=text_font)
relic_menu.grid(row=current_row, column=1, padx=(15, 0))

relic_no_entry = Entry(add_relics_window, width=5, justify=CENTER, font=text_font, bg=label_color, fg=label_font_color)
relic_no_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=2)

clicked_rarity = StringVar()
clicked_rarity.set("Select Option")
rarity_menu = OptionMenu(add_relics_window, clicked_rarity, *rarity_list)
rarity_menu.config(bg=btn_color, fg=font_color, font=text_font)
rarity_menu.grid(row=current_row, column=3)

quantity_entry = Entry(add_relics_window, width=5, validate='key', validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'), justify=CENTER, font=text_font, bg=label_color, fg=label_font_color)
quantity_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=4)

clicked_mission = StringVar()
clicked_mission.set("Select Option")
mission_menu = OptionMenu(add_relics_window, clicked_mission, *mission_list)
mission_menu.config(bg=btn_color, fg=font_color, font=text_font)
mission_menu.grid(row=current_row, column=5)

clicked_planet = StringVar()
clicked_planet.set("Select Option")
planet_menu = OptionMenu(add_relics_window, clicked_planet, *planet_list)
planet_menu.config(bg=btn_color, fg=font_color, font=text_font)
planet_menu.grid(row=current_row, column=6, padx=(15, 0))

location_entry = Entry(add_relics_window, width=25, justify=CENTER, font=text_font, bg=label_color, fg=label_font_color)
location_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=7, padx=15)

clicked_rotation = StringVar()
clicked_rotation.set("Select Option")
rotation_menu = OptionMenu(add_relics_window, clicked_rotation, *rotation_list)
rotation_menu.config(bg=btn_color, fg=font_color, font=text_font)
rotation_menu.grid(row=current_row, column=8)

drop_chance_entry = Entry(add_relics_window, width=10, justify=CENTER, font=text_font, bg=label_color, fg=label_font_color)
drop_chance_entry.grid(row=current_row, column=9)

clicked_obtained = StringVar()
clicked_obtained.set("Select Option")
obtained_menu = OptionMenu(add_relics_window, clicked_obtained, *answer_list)
obtained_menu.config(bg=btn_color, fg=font_color, font=text_font)
obtained_menu.grid(row=current_row, column=10)

current_row += 1

enter_button = Button(add_relics_window, text="Submit", command=submit, bg=btn_color, fg=font_color, font=text_font, relief=GROOVE)
enter_button.grid(row=10, column=7, pady=(30, 0))
    
def submit():
    data_list = []
    for part in warframe_part_list:
            list = (prime_entry.get(), part, clicked_relic.get(), relic_no_entry.get(), clicked_rarity.get(), quantity_entry.get(), clicked_mission.get(), clicked_planet.get(), location_entry.get(), clicked_rotation.get(), drop_chance_entry.get(), clicked_obtained.get())
             data_list.append(list)

connections = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, database=database)
cursors = connections.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO relics (prime, part, relic, relic_no, rarity, quantity, drop_mission, drop_planet, drop_location, drop_rotation, drop_chance, obtained) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
cursors.executemany(sql, data_list)
connections.commit()
connections.close()
```

Database output should look like this:

1. Blueprint,  Lith, P11, Rare,     5, Defense,  Void
2. Neuroptics, Meso, R4,  Common,   3, Capture,  Void
3. Chassis,    Neo,  S17, Uncommon, 1, Survival, Void
4. Systems,    Axi,  K6,  Uncommon, 0, Survival, Void

Loop is replacing each sublist instead of adding them and I end up with the last list 4 times in the main list.

You're help is much appreciated.

ps. How do I shorten below code to add all list simultaneously in a single loop. eg.

```
for x in companion_type_list:
            sql = "INSERT INTO companions_list (companion, type, my_rank, reactor, forma, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            data = (x, 'Sentinel', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(sql, data)
```

Looping through all sub lists?

```
 # $$$$  Add All Companions  $$$$$
    companion_type_list = [
        'Sentinels',
        'MOA',
        'Hound',
        'Kubrow',
        'Kavat',
        'Predasite',
        'Vulpaphyla']
    
    sentinel_list = ['Carrier', 'Dethcube', 'Diriga', 'Djinn', 'Helios', 'Nautilus', 'Oxylus', 'Shade', 'Taxon', 'Wyrm']
    moa_list = ['Lambeo', 'Nychus', 'Oloro', 'Para']
    hound_list = ['Bhaira', 'Dorma', 'Hec']
    kubrow_list = ['Chesa', 'Charger', 'Huras', 'Raksa', 'Sahasa', 'Sunika']
    kavat_list = ['Adarza', 'Smeeta', 'Vasca']
    predasite_list = ['Medjay', 'Pharaoh', 'Vizier']
    vulpaphyla_list = ['Crescent', 'Panzer', 'Sly']

    connections = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, database=database)
    cursors = connections.cursor()
    cursors.execute('SELECT id FROM companions_list')
    records = cursors.fetchone()
    if records is None:
        for x in sentinel_list:
            sql = "INSERT INTO companions_list (companion, type, my_rank, reactor, forma, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            data = (x, 'Sentinel', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(sql, data)
        for x in moa_list:
            sql = "INSERT INTO companions_list (companion, type, my_rank, reactor, forma, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            data = (x, 'Moa', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(sql, data)
        for x in hound_list:
            sql = "INSERT INTO companions_list (companion, type, my_rank, reactor, forma, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            data = (x, 'Hound', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(sql, data)
        for x in kubrow_list:
            sql = "INSERT INTO companions_list (companion, type, my_rank, reactor, forma, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            data = (x, 'Kubrow', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(sql, data)
        for x in kavat_list:
            sql = "INSERT INTO companions_list (companion, type, my_rank, reactor, forma, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            data = (x, 'Kavat', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(sql, data)
        for x in predasite_list:
            sql = "INSERT INTO companions_list (companion, type, my_rank, reactor, forma, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            data = (x, 'Predasite', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(sql, data)
        for x in vulpaphyla_list:
            sql = "INSERT INTO companions_list (companion, type, my_rank, reactor, forma, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            data = (x, 'Vulpaphyla', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(sql, data)
        connections.commit()
        connections.close()
```

Comment: Post the MySQL error you get.

Comment: Semi fixed it. (The error was using string instead of list/tuple/dictionary). See my update for the current issue.

Comment: It is still not clear what your issues are and still not posting the error.

Comment: No problem, my bad, let me clarify:  I have a tkinter window with 4 rows of entry fields and drop-down menu's. I need to import all 4 rows at the same time with one button click into MySQL database. (each on its own row). The updated code I have submitted creates the for list which imports into 4 separate rows in MySQL. The problem now is, it overwrites each row and I get the last list in the loop four times.

Comment: How do you create those entries? What is `warframe_part_list`? How are those checkbuttons related to inserting data to database? You used same set of entry widgets in the for loop inside `submit()`, so how do you expect they are from the *four rows of entry fields*? It is better to provide a [mre] and state clear what your problem is, otherwise no one can help.

Comment: I have added the rest of the code. Each item in that list creates a row of entry widgets starting with the item as the name of that row. So I need the user to fill out all four rows of fields and submit once, instead of filling out each row individually and submit. Don't worry about the check buttons, it's a different part of the program, not related to this section. I got that section to work. I just need the database sorted, then I'm good.

Comment: Your code has indentation issue.  It seems like you used same set of variables (i.e. `relic_no_entry`, `quantity_entry`, etc) in the for loop, so they will refer the last row of widgets after the for loop.  Suggest to use a dictionary to store those widgets in a row using `part` as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used same set of variables in the for loop, so those set of variables will reference the last row of widgets after the for loop.

Suggest to use a dictionary to store those widgets in a row using `part` as the key:

```py
rows_of_widgets = {}  # dictionary to store the widgets in each row
current_row = 5
for part in warframe_part_list:
    # create those widgets as in the posted code
    ...
    # save current row of widgets into the dictionary
    rows_of_widgets[part] = [clicked_relic, relic_no_entry,
                             clicked_rarity, quantity_entry,
                             clicked_mission, clicked_planet,
                             location_entry, clicked_rotation,
                             drop_chance_entry, clicked_obtained]

    current_row += 1
```

Then modify `submit()` to loop through the dictionary:

```py
def submit():
    data_list = []
    for part in warframe_part_list:
        values = [prime_entry.get(), part] + [item.get() for item in rows_of_widgets[part]]
        data_list.append(values)

    # insert data_list into database table
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

## Note: This is the shortened code, not the fix.

```py
# $$$$  Add All Companions  $$$$$
    companion_type_list = [
        'Sentinels',
        'MOA',
        'Hound',
        'Kubrow',
        'Kavat',
        'Predasite',
        'Vulpaphyla']
    
    sentinel_list = ['Carrier', 'Dethcube', 'Diriga', 'Djinn', 'Helios', 'Nautilus', 'Oxylus', 'Shade', 'Taxon', 'Wyrm']
    moa_list = ['Lambeo', 'Nychus', 'Oloro', 'Para']
    hound_list = ['Bhaira', 'Dorma', 'Hec']
    kubrow_list = ['Chesa', 'Charger', 'Huras', 'Raksa', 'Sahasa', 'Sunika']
    kavat_list = ['Adarza', 'Smeeta', 'Vasca']
    predasite_list = ['Medjay', 'Pharaoh', 'Vizier']
    vulpaphyla_list = ['Crescent', 'Panzer', 'Sly']

    connections = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=password, host=host, database=database)
    cursors = connections.cursor()
    cursors.execute('SELECT id FROM companions_list')
    records = cursors.fetchone()
    SQL = "INSERT INTO companions_list (companion, type, my_rank, reactor, forma, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    if records is None:
        for x in sentinel_list:
            data = (x, 'Sentinel', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(SQL, data)
        for x in moa_list:
            data = (x, 'Moa', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(SQL, data)
        for x in hound_list:
            data = (x, 'Hound', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(SQL, data)
        for x in kubrow_list:
            data = (x, 'Kubrow', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(SQL, data)
        for x in kavat_list:
            data = (x, 'Kavat', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(SQL, data)
        for x in predasite_list:
            data = (x, 'Predasite', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(SQL, data)
        for x in vulpaphyla_list:
            data = (x, 'Vulpaphyla', 0, 'No', 0, "None")
            cursors.execute(SQL, data)
        connections.commit()
        connections.close()
```